# Ionic Cordova Media Not Found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm writing an Ionic app, and I'm trying to play an mp3 file using the Cordova Media (org.apache.cordova.media).  But when I use the Media object in JavaScript I get: `ReferenceError: Media is not defined`

I've used both plain JS and ngCordova and the result is the same.

Plain JS:

```
var media = new Media('js/components/timer/startBell.mp3');
media.play();
```

ngCordova flavor:

```
var startBell source = ('js/components/timer/startBell.mp3');
var mediaSource = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(startBellSrc);
                    var promise = mediaSource.promise;
                    var mediaStatus = mediaSource.mediaStatus;
                    var media = mediaSource.media;
                    $cordovaMedia.play(media);
```

I'm new to both Cordova and to Ionic, so I'm not sure if I need to add something to the run in the app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ionic',
    'my.custom.module'
])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaMedia) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        **//add some cordova media plugin initialization code here???**
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

full stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: Media is not defined
    at Object.newMedia (http://localhost:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js:1817:25)
    at Object.countdown (http://localhost:8100/js/components/timer/timer-service.js:14:53)
    at Scope.$scope.startTimer (http://localhost:8100/js/main/main-controller.js:6:30)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18227:21
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42490:9
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20089:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20187:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42489:13)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10381:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `ionic serve` method to preview your app, which isn't able to run Cordova (since its just a browser, not actually a mobile environment). You'll have to try testing by running your app inside of an emulator.

Comment: exactly the same issue in the real device.

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ why there a solution if you still have the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

As Jeremy stated *Media* is not running on browser, you should try it on real device. If you are on real device and still have problem then all steps like below:

Add platforms

```
ionic platform add android
ionic platform add ios
```

Install Apache Cordova Media Plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
```

Include ng-cordova.js or ng-cordova.min.js in your index.html file before cordova.js

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Inject ngCordova as an Angular dependency

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

Inject both *$cordovaMedia* and *$ionicPlatform* to your controller and use Media plugin after your platform is ready

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaMedia){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        var src = ionic.Platform.isAndroid() ?
                       ? "/android_asset/www/audio/src.mp3"
                       : "audio/src.mp3";

        var src = new Media(crowdSrc, null, null, crowdCallback);
        src.play();
    })
})
```

I hope this helps.